# Weird space on top of PostgreSQL questions should be removed

Tags: bug, status-completed

When looking for questions using [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) in Stack Overflow; there used to be an ad on top of the questions. Now, it seems gone, but the space is still there.

[image: screenshot]

I think the ad should be back there, or at least make use of that space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ads here have been burninated.