# Blank space above Inno Setup questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

I have noticed that the [inno-setup](/questions/tagged/inno-setup) page on Stack Overflow have a space above the questions, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

I think the problem is related to a [similar problem with the PostgreSQL tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131627/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an issue with the sponsored ad and it has been fixed.  Please don't hesitate to help us out and let us know if you see anymore blanks :)

Comment: Are you Stack Exchange employee?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - yup, that's Jamie, she does a lovely job taking care of ads on SO and much more!

Comment: @Nick yip - Jamie Gingerelli, Ad Operations Campaign Manager. She does appear in the [Team page](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) but without link to any profile. BTW congrats for updating your gravatar picture! ;)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Thanks for pointing that out -- I added some credentials to my profile, it's all very offical.

Comment: Sure thing Jamie! Linking to [your welcome page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/welcome-valued-associate-jamie-gingerelli/) would make it complete but what you did so far is more than I could ask for. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd oh yea, done and done

Comment: Awesome and perfect! :)