# Layout spacing issue on newest questions for sponsored tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, sponsored-tags

I noticed a layout issue when clicking on sponsored tags.  When clicking on tag [android](/questions/tagged/android) I got a layout like this with a large section of white-space:

[image]

This same thing happened for the tag [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook).

I replicated this in both Firefox, Chrome and IE. And the problem continued after a cache refresh and shutting down the browsers. This is not happening with non-sponsored tags.

I am aware that this space is for the sponsored links but it has not been loading.  On many attempts at loading the tags, this has been blank with no sponsored link data appearing.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Blank space above Inno Setup questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132014/blank-space-above-inno-setup-questions), [Weird space on top of PostgreSQL questions should be removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131627/weird-space-on-top-of-postgresql-questions-should-be-removed)

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168943/188613 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141554/broken-layouts-for-special-tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug resulting from the div being created in anticipation of a tag sponsorship being served from our ad server, but no sponsorship being delivered (typically because it was not renewed or not generated yet). Basically: SO and our ad server did not communicate well when it came to tag sponsorships.

It was resolved by (1) allowing us to 'expire' a div at a given time, rather than having to manually go in and kill the sponsorship on SO *and* our ad server, and (2) either not serving a the tag sponsorship div or collapsing it if the content was not delivered from our ad server.

Soooo... more than three years later, I'm marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/tag-page-shows-lots-of-empty-space) related?

Answer (score 1):

The gap is for Sponsored Links. It has just been put up.

Android tag:
[image: Android]

Facebook tag:
[image: Facebook]

Comment: right, I understand that but the data has not been loading.  Numerous times it keeps appearing blank and not loading.

Comment: Not sure, it is loading fine for me (FF12). Try clearing your cache? EDIT: Just tested on IE, and it works fine also. Probably some initial choking.