# Broken Layouts for Special Tags

Tags: support, design, sponsored-tags

Basically all pages that include a query for one of the specialty tags (i.e [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [amazon-elb](/questions/tagged/amazon-elb), [amazon-ec2](/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2)) are showing a massive amount of whitespace above the query result (questions). I'm not sure if this is cross-browser and resolution however I'm getting the issue when viewing the site on Mac OSX, using Version 21.0.1180.57 beta.

Screenshots:

[image: two]

[image: amazon]

[image: chrome]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stop using an advertisement blocker, and those spaces will be filled with the sponsor messages attached to these tags. :-)

[image: chrome tag without blocking the advertisements]

Comment: that would explain it hahaha