# Everyone loves Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, advertising

So over on Super User I noticed a weird big empty space between the title of a question and the actual body of the post:

[image]

Chrome dev tools says that it's the following div:

```
<div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow" id="adzerk1"></div>
```

I haven't noticed this on any other SE sites. I would have pointed this out on Super User Meta, but since it specifically names Stack Overflow, I brought it here.

So: what's up with the empty div? And shouldn't it be given a site-specific class (`everyonelovessuperuser`)? Or at least make it network wide (`everyonelovesstackexchange`)? Or let's just cut to the chase and make it `everyoneloveswafflesandunicorns`.

### A-ha!

So the empty div is addressed. But the main issue remains: why the extra love for Stack Overflow? I mean, I love SO as much as everyone, but don't the other Trilogy sites deserve some action? Every body loves S(O|F|U|E)? I'm still pulling for the waffles and unicorns, but this is still unfair!

Comment: Ads are reduced if you have 200+ rep. This does not seem to be the case for you on SU

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are using an adblocker that leaves the div in place but blocks the image.

You have less than 200 rep on SU, so you are still served [all advertisements](https://superuser.com/privileges/reduced-ads) *normally*. This is what it should look like instead:

[image: advertisement]

Given the title of the post you show, your question is rather ironic. Not only does the server not know you blocked the image, neither did you! :-P

As for the div id `everyonelovesstackoverflow`; it's an *ancient* div id. It predates both SuperUser and ServerFault; it is already present on Stack Overflow in February 2009 (SF started [April 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/server-fault-private-beta-begins/), SU [July 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/logo-contest-winner-for-superusercom/)). If you look at the source of this [WayBack Machine archive copy from 2009-02-11 of "Battle of the Languages [closed]"](http://web.archive.org/web/20090211042202/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530102/battle-of-the-languages-closed) you'll find the id already in use. I guess everybody at SE loves the div name and it stayed, even when first the site expanded to a trinity and later to a multitude.

Comment: But it *only* occurs on Super User. Every other SE site, even those that I don't have an account on or have <200 rep are unaffected.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I think most SE sites don't have advertisements in the first place.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar As I understand it, ads are only shown on the trilogy sites, not the rest of SE. Also, if you have 200 rep on a particular site, then the banner ads won't display at all for you.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Also, you have 200+ rep in most places. Try ServerFault, you have < 200 there too. On the other sites you have enough rep for those ads to be removed, and most sites don't have ads (yet) anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right, it's across the Trilogy.